# how can i retrieve text from textview

Tags: iphone

I have a text view with 3 lines of data.

eg: abcde
    efghi
    jklmn

Now i need to retrieve the middle line text(efghi).

These 3 lines are unwrap text.

How can i  can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *textViewString = textView.text;
NSArray *array = [textViewString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *stringYouWanted = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Done.

But obviously this isn't the best solution. As soon as someone uses more than one space between words, you're screwed. From the info you've given us though, this is probably your best bet.